# zend navigation single level menu using xml file

Tags: zend-framework, zend-navigation

With zend framework how do i create a single level menu?

I followed a tutorial and the person created a two level dropdown menu. I want to just remove home. I've modified the navigation.xml file a couple times and it caused a fatal error.

What xml markup do i need to promote the children of home as the parent level menus? As in i don't need a home button at all.

**Desired outcome:**

> - who
> - why
> - what
> - speaker
> - resources

**Current outcome:**

> - home
>
>   • who
>
>   • what
>
>   • when
>
>   • why

**Current navigation.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configdata>
  <nav>
    <home>
      <label>Home</label>
      <controller>page</controller>
      <action>index</action>
      <module>default</module>
      <pages>
        <why>
          <label>why</label>
          <controller>page</controller>
          <action>why</action>
          <module>default</module>
        </why>
        <who>
          <label>who</label>
          <controller>page</controller>
          <action>who</action>
        </who>
        <resources>
          <label>resources</label>
          <controller>page</controller>
          <action>resources</action>
        </resources>
        <signin>
          <label>sign in</label>
          <controller>account</controller>
          <action>login</action>
          <module>default</module>
        </signin>
      </pages>
    </home>
  </nav>
```

...

**application/Bootstrap.php:**

```
<?php function _initViewHelpers() {
   $this->bootstrap('layout);
   // ... Skipping to relevant part
    $navContainerConfig = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/navigation.xml', 'nav');
    $navContainer = new Zend_Navigation($navContainerConfig);
    $view->navigation($navContainer);
} ?>
```

**layouts/default.phtml**

```
<div class="navigation"><?php print $this->navigation(); ?></div>
```

Comment: Can you provide us some code about how you render the navigation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configdata>
  <nav>
     <why>
      <label>why</label>
      <controller>page</controller>
      <action>why</action>
      <module>default</module>
    </why>
    <who>
      <label>who</label>
      <controller>page</controller>
      <action>who</action>
    </who>
    <resources>
      <label>resources</label>
      <controller>page</controller>
      <action>resources</action>
    </resources>
    <signin>
      <label>sign in</label>
      <controller>account</controller>
      <action>login</action>
      <module>default</module>
    </signin>
 </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about `setMaxDepth()` and `setMinDepth()`? You can set how deep you want your menu to be rendered:

```
<?= $this->navigation()->menu()
                       ->setMinDepth(1)
                       ->setMaxDepth(2)
                       ->render() . PHP_EOL; ?>
```

Also, you can find more information about the [navigation view helper in the official manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.navigation.menu). These information are often more relevant than the ones you can find in tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to just adjust your container to display only the links you want displayed. In this case you would just remove the `Home` elements from your xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configdata>
  <nav>
      <pages>
        <why>
          <label>why</label>
          <controller>page</controller>
          <action>why</action>
          <module>default</module>
        </why>
        <who>
          <label>who</label>
          <controller>page</controller>
          <action>who</action>
        </who>
        <resources>
          <label>resources</label>
          <controller>page</controller>
          <action>resources</action>
        </resources>
        <signin>
          <label>sign in</label>
          <controller>account</controller>
          <action>login</action>
          <module>default</module>
        </signin>
      </pages>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you remove the Home menu from the XML file , you get an exception

> Zend_Navigation_Exception: Invalid argument: Unable to determine class to instantiate in C:\www\project\library\Zend\Navigation\Page.php on line 235